# iOS take "homebutton + powerbutton" screenshot from rotated view is upside down

Tags: ios, rotation, core-graphics, screenshot

when a user makes a screenshot with the press of homebutton and powerbutton than is the screenshot upside down. The device does never autorotate. I observe `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` and if it is in landscape, I will show the rotated view. Depending on left or right device orientation

This happens when I show a view that is rotated with this code

```
CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
landscape.transform = rotationTransform;
```

Here are the rotation methods of the viewcontroller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I disable autorotate and force the rotation:

```
- (void)forceOrientationChange {
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    switch (deviceOrientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft: {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
            rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
            landscape.transform = rotationTransform;
            break;
        }
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight: {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
            rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90));
            landscape.transform = rotationTransform;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But you never change the interface orientation?

Comment: Hi David, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

```
- (void)forceOrientationChange {
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    switch (deviceOrientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft: {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
            rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
            landscape.transform = rotationTransform;
            break;
        }
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight: {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
            rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90));
            landscape.transform = rotationTransform;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```